How to embed a HYPERLINK() to a Google Sheets file in the body of a mailto: HYPERLINK() in Google Sheets?
I want the body of a Google Sheets mailto: to include a HYPERLINK() to another Google Sheets file.
A Google Sheets mailto: HYPERLINK() seems to misinterpret a HYPERLINK() to another Google Sheets file in the body. It passes syntax check, but the result is plain text in the Draft and at the destination Inbox.
I've tried escaping my double quotes around the URL to embed. I've tried HYPERLINK()-ing a cell containing the target file URL as a link and as plain text, with and without double quotes. All I get in the message body is plain text, both in the draft of the message and at the destination Inbox.
My goal is user-friendliness: to have the body of the message include a link such as "Phil's file" which the addressee can open, instead of the mile-long Google Sheets URL for Phil's file.
My Google Sheets creation gives the ultimate user a simple means of emailing files to destinations by familiar names. A script addition to my creation isn't satisfactory, because the users need a "click the link" solution.
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK("mailto:"&C2:C&"?Subject=Here is your call list&Body=Hi "&ARRAYFORMULA(E2:E)&"!"&"%0A%0AThanks for helping.%0A%0A"&D2:D,B2:B)))
I hope this will suffice. The link to a wide-open, generic edition of my table is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16UE0JFjQ-rZ8bugjqgYRKNy7r4Lt4ut2lqRBJO5HU8k/edit?usp=sharing

Please don't use external links to show your sample data, as they aren't guaranteed to be static, and they aren't always accessible by other readers. Instead, please [edit] your question to include some sample data in the question itself as a markdown table. Users will then be able to run your sample code and formula in their own sheet to reproduce your issue.

This question is similar to: Insert text with hyperlink in Gmail with Google Script?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Make sure to provide data as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Tried =ENCODEURL()?
